# Check and modify functions default argument values

Tags: javascript

I have the following function:

```
const setDefaults = (func, defArgs) => {
  //should return the func with default arguments modified
  // so that in case that an argument is not passed to the function,
  // but it is provided in default Argument, the default argumnt is used
}
```

`func`: is a function that needs to have default parameters assigned from the `defArgs`

`defArgs`: set of default arguments

For example:

```js
const greet = name => `Hi, ${name}!`

setDefaults(greet, {name: 'friend'})

greet(); // Hi, friend!
```

So far I have started diving into `func.toString()` and thinking about modifying the original function as a string and then eval the output, but that seems a bit verbose, so I was wondering if there is any better way to do this.

Comment: This is not possible in JavaScript. There are no "default values" attached to a function that you could manipulate. A default initialiser on a parameter is indistinguisable from code running inside the function body.

Comment: So yes, going with the `toString()` representation is your best bet, otherwise you wouldn't even know the parameter names. It might be better to write a wrapper that only considers positional arguments (i.e. adding default values by argument index, not by name).

Comment: WHY do you need to change parameter names - it doesn't matter for JS. You can't modify function since you defined it with "const" otherwise you could just asign it to `new Function('name',[...params], 'body')`. If you show us why do you need this we can explain why you don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
greet(); // Hi, friend!
```

You can't modify the original function because it's a `const`. If you mean to do something like this:

```
const greet = name => `Hi, ${name}!`
const parasiticGreet = setDefaults(greet, {name: 'friend'})
parasiticGreet(); // Hi, friend!
```

It is possible but I would simplify it like this:

```js
const greet = name => `Hi, ${name}!`
const setDefaults = (func, defArgs = []) => (...args) => func(...defArgs.map((x, i) => args[i] === undefined ? x : args[i]));
const parasiticGreet = setDefaults(greet, ['friend']);
console.log(parasiticGreet()); // Hi, friend!
```